# how can i access this data from my ajax to my controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

```
$('#loginForm').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login/identifying_usertype');

var url = $('#signinForm').attr('action');

var email = $('#loginEmail').val();
var password = $('#loginPass').val();

var postData = {
                'email' : email,
                'password' : password
                };

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : url,
                    data : postData,
                    success: function(response){

                        alert(data);

                        },
                        error: function (XHR, status, error){
                            console.log('error', error);
                        }
                    });
```

I have an error on my console it says Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined. when my data is on postData array what could be the problem on this one how can i access this data on my controller

Comment: @David i commented that alert what I'm really trying to do is to access those variables on my controller do you have any idea how?

Comment: did you check the values of your variables url, email, password? are they correct?

Comment: If you responce is an json, you should add datatype to your ajax call. In your controller/model return your data.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with a controller or any of your server-side code.  You simply have a function where you're trying to use a variable that doesn't exist:

```
function(response){
    alert(data);
}
```

The `data` variable isn't defined anywhere.  If you're examining the response, then surely you meant to alert the `response` variable instead?:

```
function(response){
    alert(response);
}
```

Of course, if `response` is anything more than a primitive value then this may not show useful results.  Conversely, you can log `response` to the console and see more information about it in your browser's debugging console:

```
function(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: oh i see thanks for that. now i dont have any errors on my console. but how can i get those variables that i pass on the url i came from laravel im new to codeigniter before i used to get the values just by doing $_POST['value'] on my controller function. but here its not working

Comment: public function identifying_usertype()
 {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  echo "$email";
  exit;
 }

Comment: @Lestah: Normally in PHP one would get POST values from the `$_POST` array.  If you're using frameworks, they may have their own way of getting POST values.  Check with the framework's documentation and examples.  Either way, at that point you're talking about server-side code which isn't present at all in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can acccess POST data in CodeIgniter using this syntax

```
$vairable_name =  $this->input->post('VARIABLE_NAME');
echo $variable_name; 
exit;
```